# applying style to `die` function in HTML

Tags: php

I am trying to apply style to PHP "die function". But its not working. Why? any reason.

```
$err = die(mysql_error());
echo '<br><br><center><font color="Green" size="5"> $err </font></center>';
```

but the output font style remains the same, that is in normal font.

Comment: using die or exit will terminate the php process, you won't even reach the echo command.

Comment: ohhh... got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can include it as part of your `die()` call. The ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php)) for `die()` tell us that it's equivalent to `exit()` ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)) which allows a string to be passed. I'm assuming you're checking for an error first, and this is when there is one, but why not do:

```
$err = mysql_error();
echo '<br><br><center><font color="Green" size="5"> '.$err.' </font></center>';
die();
```

or

```
die('<br><br><center><font color="Green" size="5"> '.mysql_error().' </font></center>');
```

Note that in the first option, I added delimiters to the string as the variable won't be evaluated in single quotes (') and only in (").